# Get Super set of Names from 2 tables in 1 column using SQL Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are 2 tables

**Table 1**

```
Tom
Amy
Phil
```

**Table 2**

```
Tom
Mary
Sunny
Tom
```

Now, I was to get the super set of thses as a result with distinct values like this:

**Result**

```
Tom
Amy
Phil
Mary
Sunny
```

How can i get that using JOINS? Please note that i want the result **UNDER 1 Column**

I can get that result using UNION but I cannot use it for some reason; I need to use joins.

Comment: Do you mean to say you can get that result using `UNION` but cannot for some reason? (UNION is how it would normally be done)

Comment: Yes, i am using hibernate (I am a beginner) and dropwizard and i cannot run UNION query using that. So, I want to use JOIN

Comment: Why can't you use Union?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables like:

select name
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.colname = t2.colname
group by name

or you can do a union:

select name from table 1 
union all
select name from table 2

I can't remember if it's union or union all, but that's how you'd ii

Comment: This throws an errror

Comment: which one?  there are two queries

Comment: oh... i see the issue with the join:

Comment: the first one.. I cannot use UNION

Comment: Yes... my bad... sorry.  You won't be able to do that with a join.  Why can you not use a union?  Do you get errors?  Did someone tell you that you have to use joins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION:

```
Select name from table1
Union Distinct
Select name from table2;
```